# SQL order by specific order

Tags: sql, mariadb

So with my current result set I get this:
[image: current]

and I'd like to order this to get something like: 
[image: desired result]

Code:

```
select count(*) as aantal_keer, concat(cast(t2.klant1 as char), '-', cast(t2.klant2 as char)) as pairname
from (
    select t.klant1, t.klant2, t.datum1, t.datum2, count(*) as aantal_overeenkomsten
    from (
        select a1.klant_idklant as klant1, a2.klant_idklant as klant2, a1.datum as datum1, a2.datum as datum2
        from aankoop a1, aankoop a2 where a2.product_idproduct = a1.product_idproduct and a2.klant_idklant < a1.klant_idklant
    ) t
    group by datum1, datum2
    having aantal_overeenkomsten > 3
) t2
group by pairname
order by pairname;
```

Comment: Why do the values change when you "order" the records?

Comment: They don't, it's a self-join with the id column. The two result sets are just the first 5 results of 208 results.

Comment: Your sample data is not good. We need to see what is that you want from data and we just see two different sets of data.

Comment: Updated with more code and larger result sets.

Comment: Ok, you have updated with images that is not so good... But there is a bigger problem than that. In your current image there are some data. Lets take a look of first few. Where are they in the desired result image ? I do not understand. Just simple take 5 rows like this: I want this: <1; 1-0><1;12-3><1;12-9>  to show like this <1;12-9><1; 1-0><1;12-3>. So we can understand the order of the same data before and after.

Answer (score 0):

Simply order by the string versions of klant1 & klant2.

```
select count(*) as aantal_keer, 
 concat(klant1, '-', klant2) as pairname
from (
    select t.klant1, t.klant2, t.datum1, t.datum2,
    count(*) as aantal_overeenkomsten
    from (
        select a1.klant_idklant as klant1, 
        a2.klant_idklant as klant2, a1.datum as datum1, a2.datum as datum2
        from aankoop a1
        join aankoop a2 on a2.klant_idklant < a1.klant_idklant and a2.product_idproduct = a1.product_idproduct
    ) t
    group by datum1, datum2
    having aantal_overeenkomsten > 3
) t2
group by klant1, klant2
order by cast(klant1 as char), cast(klant2 as char);
```

Comment: I get a similar result as the order by with the pairname string.

Comment: @teste Changed. Ok now?

Comment: @LukStorms This will not yield expected result as int will make sure that 11 should com after 2

Comment: Ok.  So also klant1 as string.

Answer (score 0):

Try `casting` the `integer` to `char` and `order` it separately

```
select count(*) as aantal_keer, concat(cast(t2.klant1 as char), '-', cast(t2.klant2 as char)) as pairname
from (
    select t.klant1, t.klant2, t.datum1, t.datum2, count(*) as aantal_overeenkomsten
    from (
        select a1.klant_idklant as klant1, a2.klant_idklant as klant2, a1.datum as datum1, a2.datum as datum2
        from aankoop a1, aankoop a2 where a2.product_idproduct = a1.product_idproduct and a2.klant_idklant < a1.klant_idklant
    ) t
    group by datum1, datum2
    having aantal_overeenkomsten > 3
) t2
group by pairname
order by cast(T1 AS char), cast(T2 AS char);
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=f83853bfe779f8cbc4c519eeaab95f0f)**

Output will be

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting with two numbers:

```
SELECT concat(T1, '-', T2) FROM tbl
    order by  T1, T2;
```

If you are starting with the numbers paired up to start with, split them as show here:

```
SELECT xx_yy FROM tbl
    ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(xx_yy, '-', 1),
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(xx_yy, '-', -1)
```